# docker-compose up failing on nodejs-application: "Error: Cannot find module"

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

So after searching for hours and reading different documentations and posts on stackoverflow I'm posting one myself.

I have trouble building my node.js application into a docker-image, getting the following **error-message** when trying **docker-compose up**:

```
Attaching to testbot_bot_1
bot_1  | internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
bot_1  |   throw err;
bot_1  |   ^
bot_1  |
bot_1  | Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/bot.js'
bot_1  |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
bot_1  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
bot_1  |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
bot_1  |     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
bot_1  |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
bot_1  |   requireStack: []
bot_1  | }
```

My **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM node:14.15.0-alpine3.10

RUN mkdir /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/

ADD package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
ADD . /usr/src/app/

CMD [ "node", "bot.js" ]
```

My **docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  bot:
    build: .
    command: node bot.js
```

Some posts lead me to believe I should add a volume-reference so I did, but it produced the same error:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  bot:
    build: .
    command: node bot.js
    volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/app
```

My **filestructure** looks like this:

```
- commands
  - (some .js files containing modules)
- config
  - (config files in .json-format)
- db
  - (some .js files containing modules)
- res
  - (imagefiles etc.)
- .dockerignore
- bot.js
- docker-compose.yml
- Dockerfile
- package.json
```

My **.dockerignore**:

```
node_modules
npm-debug.log
Dockerfile
.dockerignore
```

Maybe it has to do with the .build parameter in my docker-compose.yml? I don't know, no clue...

I also already tried `docker-compose down -v` and then `docker-compose up` but unfortunately that didn't change anything.

Also I did not link any Ports, because my application only has outgoing connections, this should be fine though, right?

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Generally I try to google first and have a look on Stackoverflow, maybe I just did not search for the right term?
Thanks a lot in advance for reading my post!

Answer (score 0):

Huh, okay so I just figured it out.

Turns out: You can't use it with a network storage.
I have my projects on my NAS and thought with docker-compose the necessary files would get copied to my local storage (or whereever) to run it.

It apparently didn't.

But copying my project to my local machine and then running it worked just fine... sigh... anyways thanks for reading my post!